# PC won't start after installing the latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: boot

My PC won't start after installing the latest version of Ubuntu. I press the button to start the PC and then I see the BIOS start, but after that I get a black screen and nothing is happening. I can't even reinstall Windows 7 or choose between Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Please help. I don't want to pay for fixing this. I don't remember the hardware, and since I can't access Windows 7, I can't tell you. The only thing that I know is that it is an HP Compaq 500bmt.

Comment: Please clarify your question with more details. Which version of ubuntu you have installed? Sounds like display driver problem.

Comment: the version of ubuntu is 11.10

Comment: Start the laptop and press F1 and see if you get any errors and paste the same here

Comment: it is a pc but anyway wait

Comment: i pressed it nothing happend again black screen

Comment: @karel this is OT actually.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a usb stick to hand you could turn it into a Ubuntu Live USB, boot into it and reinstall grub, this may help. Once in the live USB install "Boot Repair" and reinstall grub using this tutorial.

[TUTORIAL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

After this restart your PC and at least this should get you back into Windows if not Ubuntu as well.
Hope this helps.

Comment: when i choose to boot from usb i get again the black screen :( wtf is happeing to my pc =/ ... any other solutions ?

Comment: What do you mean choose to boot from USB, do you mean once you have hit the Ubuntu options menu where you choose to install, boot into live and other options, or do you get the black screen as soon as you pass the bios?

Comment: i start my pc and then the brand of the pc (compaq) and down left it says esc for boot f10 for boot from lan etc . i press esc and resolution of screen changes and then it says to choose how i want to boot and i have some options . i press the one that is the usb and then nothing...

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the Ubuntu is correctly on the USB stick? Do have have another computer to test it with?

Comment: Also is there any way you could try booting from a Ubuntu CD rather then USB stick? As from your description it seems you do not have the option of specifically booting from USB.

Comment: i checked the usb on my laptop and it worked. i burned ubuntu-iso into a dvd and tried to install it in  my pc again black screen . i checked it on laptop and worked .

Comment: Are you sure that your PC has a DVD drive and not a CD drive? Also would it be possible for you to enter the bios "setup" and see if you could change the boot order? I would suggest putting the CD/DVD drive at the top and then USB(Could be named " removable storage") next and then HDD and then Network boot. Now attempt to boot from USB and disk again.

Comment: it has a dvd drive . and i changed the priority but nothing happened again . i suppose that by having the pc on and the bios running it is not a hardware problem right?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a hardware problem to me. I know this may sound patronizing but have you tried inserting the USB into a different USB port, more specifically in a rear port rather than one at the front of the PC?

Comment: hmm no let me check from behind

Comment: oh my god ... i feel so stupid... well ubuntu from the back ports works

Comment: I'm so glad I could be of some help, now you can boot into Ubuntu I would suggest following the tutorial I linked in my answer so that you can boot into the operating systems you already have installed rather than reinstalling and loosing your data.

Comment: Out of interest, have you managed to recover your Ubuntu and Windows?